# Ican't update/upgrade with apt or apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, restricted

Whenever I try to update it gets stuck at 32% every time and fails.

```
someone@somewhere:~/$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
Get:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release [6,596 B]                                                                                                                                               
Ign:3 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease                                                                                                                 
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Get:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release.gpg [473 B]                                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release                                                                                                          
Hit:7 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Hit:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                          
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]                                          
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                      
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                              
Hit:13 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                
Hit:15 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                           
Get:16 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]                                                         
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                           
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                           
Get:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]                                   
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Ign:21 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages        
Ign:22 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Get:24 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [320 kB]
Get:25 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [227 kB]
Ign:26 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
32% [Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)]
```

It's preventing me from upgrading packages or updating the package list.

Comment: check what is inside the `/var/log/apt/term.log` and let us know.
You may also look in other logs files like `var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log` log file.

Comment: You have a terrifying mix of sources there: Precise, Wily, and Xenial all mixed together. Disable or delete all wrong-version sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some of the other succestions around `/etc/apt/sources.list` I started playing aroundin there and found that if I changed the server from `ca.archive.ubuntu.com` to `us.archive.ubuntu.com` it suddenly worked.  Possible problem with the Canadian server?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are unsure what may be the problem with `apt` or `apt-get` you can check the log files for the details. This is rather a general answer, but it should provide you the clue.

By default `apt-get` (apt) logs can be found in `/var/log/apt/term.log`, if you haven't set otherwise in the `apt-get` configuration file.

You may also look in other logs files like `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

File `/var/log/dpkg.log` is also valid to check because `apt-get` is based on `dpkg`.